# How do I handle a SQL LITE ID/primary key exception without my app crashing/ Android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite

It works fine when a user puts in the correct ID but breaks when its incorrect, username is a int which is my primary key i want to catch the exception and tell the user incorrect id, but what exception do i need? or how do i catch sql lite exceptions any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the SDK's **SQLiteDatabase**'s [**insert**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) method and assume that a failed insert (the long returned is **-1** rather then 1 or greater).

If you wanted more specific control/error handling then you could use the **SQLiteDatabase**'s [**insertOrThrow**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insertOrThrow(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) method to then handle the [SQLiteConstraintException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteConstraintException.html).